# Let $R$ be an integral domain and $I$ be a prime ideal of $R$. If $R/I$ is a Euclidean domain, will $R$ be a unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $I$ be a prime ideal of $R$. If $R/I$ is a Euclidean domain, will $R$ be a unique factorization domain?

I have no idea to prove or disprove this... should I prove or disprove?

Comment: My immediate reaction to questions worded like this is to say  that it depends on $R$ and $I$. I can think of more than one way to interpret the question, and you might find it helpful to phrase it more formally.

Comment: To be more specific, are you assuming that $R/I$ is a Euclidean domain for all prime ideals $I$ of $R$, or that there exists an ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $R/I$ is a Euclidean Domain?

Comment: Do you know any nonunique factorization domains?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Fields are EDs and non-UFDs can have residue fields.

Comment: should I prove or disprove?

Comment: Understand my hint and you will know whether to prove or disprove (and how).

Comment: @RenShiquan Here's a (hopefully not overkill) complementary hint to this one. Sometimes it's good to consider extremes. Let $R$ be as bad as possible, but make sure that $R/I$ is as good as possible. This is the direction of anon's hint